# Closing socket on program termination

Tags: java, sockets

I have a server/client program that lets clients send requests to the server, my program works fine but I have encountered an issue, I noticed that when I'm testing the program over and over again the port I used in the previous run cannot be used in the new run, and the old socket is never closed, this will eat up the CPU on my computer until I close my IDE and then close the java instances in task manager. I have the warning underline in my IDE telling me that my socket is never closed, my question is how exactly do I close my socket when I terminate my program to make sure that it doesn't eat up my CPU and keep occupying the port?

Comment: Are you sure your program is terminating? E.g. if you are using swing, do you call the `jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`? Because otherwise window is hidden, but the application keeps running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work in all types of applications (server, client, swing, what have you)

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> { 
  try {
    socket.close(); 
  } catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

> how exactly do I close my socket

With the `close()` method.

> when I terminate my program

In a shutdown hook if really necessary, but surely you can close your program cleanly?

> to make sure that it doesn't eat up my CPU and keep occupying the port?

The port being in use does not last forever, and certainly does *not* eat up CPU.

You need to look into `ServerSocket.setReuseAddress(true)`, and note that you must call it before you bind the socket.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `socket` is closed. The following code should do the trick for you.

```
try {
      socket.close();
      System.out.println("Server has been successfully shut down!");
} catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note that if you are trying to hit `Ctrl+Z` to stop your application, the process is not terminated. Essentially, `Ctrl+Z` sends the `SIGTSTP` signal that is responsible for **pausing** the process and therefore, all resources used by the application (including network sockets) will still be alive.